# Logstash input and output fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have filebeat writing to logstash writing to elastic search. I am trying to pass through a field or tag from filebeat logstash output.

The logstash input looks like this:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
```

The current output looks like this:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "{{elasticsearch_hosts_nginx_dev}}" ]
        index => "nginx_dev-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

What I an trying to achieve is receive a variable from the input and use it in the index name like so:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "{{elasticsearch_hosts_nginx_dev}}" ]
        index => "nginx_${variable_from_input}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Any help would be apprciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. You access the field with: %{env}

To the filebeat.yml file add:

```
fields:
  env: dev
  bu: rsk
```

To logstash.conf add the following:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "{{elasticsearch_hosts_nginx}}" ]
        index => "nginx_%{env}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```